# Table of contents: no chapter number in section label

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

My table of contents looks like this:

```
 I        Chapter I
 I.1      Section I.1
 I.2      Section I.2

 II       Chapter II
 II.1     Section II.1
 II.2     Section II.2
```

How can I make it look like this:

```
 I        Chapter I
 1        Section I.1
 2        Section I.2

 II       Chapter II
 1        Section II.1
 2        Section II.2
```

?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\centering\normalfont}
{\itshape \partname~\thepart}{1.0em}
{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\dottedcontents{chapter}[3.0em]{\scshape\bfseries\vspace{1.0em}}{2.5em}{0pc}
\dottedcontents{section}[3.0em]{}{3.5em}{0.75pc}

\begin{document}

\startcontents[parts]
\part{Part I}

\printcontents[parts]{}{0}{}

\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I.1}
\section{Section I.2}

\chapter{Chapter II}
\section{Section II.1}
\section{Section II.2}

\stopcontents[parts]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Put: \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} just after \renewcommand{chapter} and also change to : \dottedcontents{section}[3.35em]{}{3.5em}{0.75pc} for the spacing

Comment: My comments solution doesn't work... breaks your section in the main document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you need.

- `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}`
- `\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter.\thesection}{1em}{}` for titles
- `\renewcommand{\p@section}{\thechapter.}` for cross references.

of course you need to adjust spacing in TOC entries.

**Example**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\centering\normalfont}
{\itshape \partname~\thepart}{1.0em}
{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter.\thesection}{1em}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\p@section}{\thechapter.}
\makeatother

\dottedcontents{chapter}[3.0em]{\scshape\bfseries\vspace{1.0em}}{2.5em}{0pc}
\dottedcontents{section}[3.0em]{}{3.5em}{0.75pc}

\begin{document}

\startcontents[parts]
\part{Part I}

\printcontents[parts]{}{0}{}

\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I.1}
\section{Section I.2}

\chapter{Chapter II}
\section{Section II.1}
\section{Section II.2}

\stopcontents[parts]

\end{document}
```

Comment: much easier than mine! +1 I needed this answer to learn that there is  \p@section that made my answer so difficult. But I will post my content in new topic for redefining sections etc.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy way to add some space between e.g. Chapter I and Section I.1 in the table of contents?

Comment: you can try `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}[\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}]`

Answer (score 2):

May be not the best and easier answer... I Redefined the sections to show deferent edry to toc and have deferent appearance in body:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\centering\normalfont}
{\itshape \partname~\thepart}{1.0em}
{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}


\titleformat{\section}{\large\bf}{}{0pt}{}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\dottedcontents{chapter}[3.0em]{\scshape\bfseries\vspace{1.0em}}{2.5em}{0pc}
\dottedcontents{section}[3.35em]{}{3.5em}{0.75pc}

\let\oldsection\section
    \makeatletter
    \def\section{%
    \@ifstar{\@Starred}{\@nonStarred}%
    }
    \def\@Starred{%
    \@ifnextchar[%
    {\GenericWarning{}{Warning: A starred section can not have parameters. I am going to ignore them!}\@StarredWith}%
    {\@StarredWithout}%
    }      
    \def\@StarredWith[#1]#2{%
    \oldsection*[\thesection]{\thechapter.\thesection\space#2}%
    }
    \def\@StarredWithout#1{
    \oldsection*{\thechapter.\thesection\space#1}%
    }
    \def\@nonStarred{%
    \@ifnextchar[%
    {\@nonStarredWith}%
    {\@nonStarredWithout}%
    }
    \def\@nonStarredWith[#1]#2{%
    \oldsection[#1]{\thechapter.\thesection\space#2}%
    }
    \def\@nonStarredWithout#1{%
    \oldsection[#1]{\thechapter.\thesection\space#1}%
    }
    \makeatother




\begin{document}

\startcontents[parts]
\part{Part I}

\printcontents[parts]{}{0}{}

\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I.1}
\section{Section I.2}

\chapter{Chapter II}
\section{Section II.1}
\section{Section II.2}


\stopcontents[parts]

\end{document}
```

You can do anything you want within your new sections in the def command.
I just made the original nonstarred without toc option to have a toc option.

Result in contents:

[image]

And in body:

[image]